# Serialize xml string to object and to json

Tags: c#, json, .net, xml, json.net

I have following xml string format where property key is random and not known but always start with alphanumeric character

```xml
<properties>
  <property key="EventId">3300</property>
  <property key="source">car</property>
  <property key="type">omega</property>
  <property key="a341414">any value</property>
  <property key="arandomstring_each_time_different">any value</property>
  ....
</properties>
```

how to achieve following format

```json
{
   "properties":
   {
      "EventId": "3300", 
      "source": "car",
      ...
   }
}
```

I tried some variation of following code, but with no luck

```cs
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(string); 
string jsonText = JsonConvert.SerializeXNode(doc);
var dynamic = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(jsonText);
```

output

```json
{
   "properties":{
      "property":[
         {
            "@key":"EventId",
            "#text":"3300"
         },
         {
            "@key":"source",
            "#text":"car"
         },
         ...
      ]
   }
}
```

Comment: Json.NET is behaving as documented in [Converting between JSON and XML](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ConvertingJSONandXML.htm): *Single child text nodes are a value directly against an element, otherwise they are accessed via #text.*  Since your `<property>` nodes have an attribute, the value is in a `#text` property.  But why use Json.NET to convert from `XElement` to `ExpandoObject`?  Why not do it directly like so?  https://dotnetfiddle.net/JzCbWd.  Is your XML more general than is shown in your question?

Comment: Thank you that solved my problem , my mind stuck in thinking that some library will solve problem, instead of simple solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Json.NET is behaving as documented in [Converting between JSON and XML](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ConvertingJSONandXML.htm):

> Single child text nodes are a value directly against an element, otherwise they are accessed via #text.

Since your `<property>` nodes have an attribute, the value is placed into in a `#text` property.

But why use Json.NET to convert from `XElement` to `ExpandoObject`?  It's simple enough to do the conversion directly using LINQ to XML:

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

IDictionary<string, object> properties = new ExpandoObject();
foreach (var property in doc.Root.Elements("property"))
    properties.Add(property.Attribute("key").Value, property.Value);
dynamic d = new ExpandoObject();
d.properties = properties;
```

Which results in, as required:

```json
{
  "properties": {
    "EventId": "3300",
    "source": "car",
    "type": "omega",
    "a341414": "any value",
    "arandomstring_each_time_different": "any value"
  }
}
```

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/JzCbWd).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to purely rely on Json.Net then you can do that as well:

```
var docInXml = XDocument.Parse("...");
var docInJson = JsonConvert.SerializeXNode(docInXml);
var semiParsedJson = JObject.Parse(docInJson);
var propertyCollection = semiParsedJson["properties"]["property"] as JArray;

var keyValueMapping = new Dictionary<string, string>();
foreach(var item in propertyCollection.Children())
{
    keyValueMapping.Add((string)item["@key"], (string)item["#text"]);
}

var result = new JObject(new JProperty("properties", JObject.FromObject(keyValueMapping)));
```

Let's see the code line-by-line:

`var docInXml = XDocument.Parse("...");`

- It parses the xml string as `XDocument`

`var docInJson = JsonConvert.SerializeXNode(docInXml);`

- It serializes the `XDocument` to json

```json
{
   "properties":{
      "property":[
         {
            "@key":"EventId",
            "#text":"3300"
         },
         {
            "@key":"source",
            "#text":"car"
         },
         {
            "@key":"type",
            "#text":"omega"
         },
         {
            "@key":"a341414",
            "#text":"any value"
         },
         {
            "@key":"arandomstring_each_time_different",
            "#text":"any value"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

`var semiParsedJson = JObject.Parse(docInJson);`

- It semi parses the json to be able to perform node traversal

`var propertyCollection = semiParsedJson["properties"]["property"] as JArray;`

- It retrieves the `property` collection as an array

`var keyValueMapping = new Dictionary<string, string>();`

- It defines a temporary storage for the key attributes and text values

`foreach(var item in propertyCollection.Children())`

- It iterates through the array's items

`keyValueMapping.Add((string)item["@key"], (string)item["#text"]);`

- It retrieves the desired fields and converts them from `JObject` to `string`
- It stores them in the intermediate storage

`JObject.FromObject(keyValueMapping)))`

- It converts the `Dictionary` into a `JObject`

```json
{
  "EventId": "3300",
  "source": "car",
  "type": "omega",
  "a341414": "any value",
  "arandomstring_each_time_different": "any value"
}
```

`var result = new JObject(new JProperty("properties", ...));`

- Finally, it creates a wrapper around the above created `JObject`

```json
{
  "properties": {
    "EventId": "3300",
    "source": "car",
    "type": "omega",
    "a341414": "any value",
    "arandomstring_each_time_different": "any value"
  }
}
```